# MySQL - LEFT JOIN with two fields

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have two tables:

- `invoices`
- `discount_vouchers`

I the `invoice` table, there are two feilds:

- `voucher_id`
- `author_voucher_ids`

The voucher_id is the direct id of the discount_vouchers table.

The author_voucher_ids is a coma separated list of IDs from the discount_vouchers table.

Is it possible to `LEFT JOIN` the invoices and discount_vouchers tables with those two fields?

I have tried with:

```
LEFT JOIN discount_vouchers ON invoices.discount_voucher_id = discount_vouchers.id OR discount_vouchers.id IN (author_voucher_ids)
```

But this is extremely slow and I need to kill the process.

I know the table invoices is designed in a wrong way, but I am searching for a solution without having to touch the existing table structure.

Thank you.

Comment: the in clause will not work as you expect on a comma-delimited value in the author_voucher_ids column

Comment: Comma separated values in a field are never ever ever ever good design. They will only lead to heartache, or... at best, very slow performance. Your `IN` operator needs a comma delimited list of ids, but you are feeding a single varchar field. It simply won't work as written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the FIND_IN_SET MySQL function:

```
LEFT JOIN discount_vouchers ON invoices.discount_voucher_id = discount_vouchers.id
OR FIND_IN_SET(discount_vouchers.id, author_voucher_ids) <> 0
```

Comment: Thanks @Jose Ramon Garcia, I accepted this answer as it works, but it is extremely slow, so I really need to change the database structure, as mentioned in the comments.